# Django Model Access

Tags: mysql, django, templates, url, foreign-keys

I'm in the process of making a Django application using a MySQL database. I'm having trouble with a detailed view for a particular table. I have a table EMAILS which holds the column USERNAME, which is a primary key for EMAILS, and also the foreign and primary key for a second table PLAYERS.

```
CREATE TABLE Emails(
Username varchar(30) PRIMARY KEY,
Email varchar (30) UNIQUE NOT NULL, 
Pass_field varchar (15),
Registered date,
User_Type varchar (15) NOT NULL 
);

CREATE TABLE Players(
Real_Name varchar (30),
Handle varchar (30) NOT NULL,
Username varchar (30) PRIMARY KEY,
Birth date,
Nationality varchar (5),
foreign key(Username) references Emails(Username)
);


class Emails(models.Model):
    email = models.CharField(max_length=30L, db_column='Email')
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30L, primary_key=True, db_column='Username')
    pass_field = models.CharField(max_length=15L, db_column='Pass_Field', blank=True) 
    registered = models.DateField(null=True, db_column='Registered', blank=True)
    user_type = models.CharField(max_length=15L, db_column='User_Type')

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.username    

class Meta:
    db_table = 'emails'

class Players(models.Model):
    real_name = models.CharField(max_length=30L, db_column='Real_Name', blank=True)
    handle = models.CharField(max_length=30L, db_column='Handle')
    username = models.ForeignKey(Emails, primary_key=True, db_column='Username')
    birth = models.DateField(null=True, db_column='Birth', blank=True) 
    nationality = models.CharField(max_length=5L, db_column='Nationality', blank=True) 

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.username

class Meta:
    db_table = 'players'
```

Those are the MySQL and Django Models, which I believe to be correct and aligned with each other.

From a page that displays a list view of a table, I have a link in each row that leads off to a detailed view of that object. I do this using a URL pattern like this

```
url(r"^player/(?P<pk>\w+)/$", views.PlayerView.as_view(), name='player'),
```

The PlayerView is defined as such:

```
class PlayerView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Players
    template_name = 'dotapp/player.html'
```

And the link looks like this:

```
/player/{{ player.username.username }}"  *HTML omitted
```

This method works for other tables in my app that have their own (non-foreign) primary key, however with PLAYER, it returns my template with no information. To me, this suggests an object is retrieved, but for some reason the associated data is not displayed. Finally, my template looks like this:

```
{% extends 'dotapp/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Player: {{ player }}</h1>
<p>
    <strong>Name:</strong> {{ player.real_name }}
</p>
<p>
    <strong>Handle:</strong> {{ player.handle }}
</p>
<p>
    <strong>Email:</strong> {{ player.username.email }}
</p>
<p>
    <strong>Birth:</strong> {{ player.birth }}
</p>
<p>
    <strong>Nationality:</strong> {{ player.nationality }}
</p>

{% endblock %}
```

I can use the python shell to view the missing data, but I have no idea why it won't show up on my PLAYER template. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default name of your object passed into the template will be `object`, so either change the references to `player` in your template, or add `context_object_name` to your class based view:

```
class PlayerView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Players
    template_name = 'dotapp/player.html'
    context_object_name = 'player'
```